# Is it possible to interpolate an HTML element into the document in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Say in my controller somewhere I have:

```
$scope.elements = [document.getElementById('a'), document.getElementById('b')];
```

and I have valid elements somewhere in the document with IDs of `a` and `b`.

I'd like to interpolate these elements directly in an HTML template, without writing JavaScript. I tried the following, and it did not work.

```
<div ng-repeat="e in elements">
    {{ e }}
</div>
```

Is this possible?

**More information about what I'm doing:**

I have content (several custom directive elements which load up their own data via AJAX) that I want to disperse between several columns. The column of the content elements will change, and the number of columns will change.

```
<column-resizer options="columnResizerOptions">
    <content1></content1>
    <content2></content2>
    ...
</column-resizer>
```

The template for `columnResizer` currently looks like this:

```
<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
<div ng-repeat="column in columns">
    <div ng-repeat="element in column">
        {{ element }}
    </div>
</div>
```

`columnResizerOptions` is information about how to resize the columns and where to place the content in the columns. In the `link` function for the `columnResizer`, I use `transclude` to grab `content1`-`contentn` and place them in arrays corresponding to the column they should be in, which I `ngRepeat` through in my template (above).

Comment: why would this be even necessary?  Any time you are using `document.getElementById()`, you are trying to program against the DOM.  Angular doesn't need to be developed in this manner.  How did the HTML content get into those elements without angular knowing about it, or being able to be told by the server when the page was rendered?  Something isn't adding up here.

Comment: can you show a bit more about what it is you are actually trying to do, and why you can't use `ng-repeat` on the data, instead of the rendered HTML?  As it stands right now, this is definitely an XY Question.  see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: I was trying to keep the question simple, but perhaps I did not include enough information. My ng-repeat is inside a directive template. My directive element contains transcluded elements which I grab in `link()` with the `transclude()` function and disperse into a set of arrays, and I'd like each array to display in a different `ng-repeat`ed `div`. I'll update the original question with this information.

Comment: This appears to be an anti pattern. *What* are you trying to achieve by solving this?

Comment: that is a bit closer to what your problem is, but why render the elements into a transclusion if you are just going to tear the HTML apart? why not pass the data as parameters to the directive directly?

Comment: can you demonstrate with some sample data what it is exactly you are passing, and what you are trying to render?

Comment: @Claies I've updated my response with additional information. Thanks for your help.

Comment: hmm, ok I think I understand now what this directive is meant to do... I suspect that the answer provided by @estus is correct, and you need to use `.outterHTML` or `.innerHTML` on your array elements, and use `ng-bind-html` to ensure the HTML is preserved.

Comment: I would wonder, however, how rendering a directive into a transclusion to re-render the HTML will affect the digest cycle; you may encounter issues with long digest loops, so rendering performance may be impacted.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you wouldn't treat your whole app the "Angular way", but you could write a directive to do this:

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .directive('interpolateHtml', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        htmlElement: '='
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element) {
        element.append(scope.htmlElement);
      }

    }

  })
```

And use it in your HTML like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="e in elements">
  <div interpolate-html html-element="e"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/5NvMA1x0C8TcwdLO2FNK?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

```
$scope.elements = [ (document.getElementById('a') || {}).outerHTML ];
```

and

```
<div ng-repeat="e in elements">
    <div ng-bind-html="e"></div>
</div>
```

You won't get data binding this way. You can use `innerHTML` or jqLite `html()` instead to get rid of extra wrappers.

> get them into the DOM without using append, as it would be cleaner.

It wouldn't. A directive with nested directives or with DOM modifications in `link` is proper way in this case, you don't have to use data binding everywhere just because Angular promotes it.